E.g. Renaming in ASP.NET Core Web API
If I have:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace API.Entities
{
    [Table("ProductOrders", Schema = "product_orders")]
    public class ProductOrders
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category? Category { get; set; }
    }
}

How can I name the Category to whatever I like?

Both the int and Category type
Preferably using annotations
E.g. rename Category to MainCategory

Second question: using the same table for multiple ones so I may have secondaryCategory referencing the same table
For example having SecondaryCategoryId and SecondaryCategory? SecondaryCategory {get; set; }
E.g. would this work?
[Table("ProductOrders", Schema = "product_orders")]
    public class ProductOrders
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("CategoryId")]
        public int? MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("MainCategoryId")]
        public Category? MainCategory { get; set; }

        [Column("CategoryId")]
        public int? SecondCategoryId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("SecondCategoryId")]
        public Category? SecondCategory { get; set; }
    }


Aboout the second question, could you please provide a more detailed description of the problem? Or maybe you can refer to this Relationship.

By this, I mean taking your answer which solved the first problem. Lets say I wanted SecondCategory. Which would reference the same table as MainCategory. Imagine I have two tables ProductOrders and Category. In ProductOrders I have MainCategory. But also want a secondaryCategory alongside that

I added some example code that may explain what I am aiming for in my post edit

I have updated my answer as below, you can refer to that and have a try.

You can rename the Category properties in your ProductOrders class to something like MainCategory and SecondaryCategory by using data annotations. Specifically, you can use the [Column] attribute to specify the column name for each property.
Here's how you can do it:
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    
    namespace API.Entities
    {
        [Table("ProductOrders", Schema = "product_orders")]
        public class ProductOrders
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            // Rename CategoryId to MainCategoryId
            [Column("CategoryId")]
            public int? MainCategoryId { get; set; }
    
            // Rename Category to MainCategory
            [ForeignKey("MainCategoryId")]
            public Category? MainCategory { get; set; }
    
            // Add a secondary category with a new column name
            [Column("SecondaryCategoryId")]
            public int? SecondaryCategoryId { get; set; }
    
            [ForeignKey("SecondaryCategoryId")]
            public Category? SecondaryCategory { get; set; }
        }
    }


Renaming CategoryId and Category: refer to the tutorials: Column names, ForeignKeyAttribute
For example:
[Table("ProductOrders", Schema = "product_orders")]
    public class ProductOrders
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("CategoryId")]
        public int? MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("MainCategoryId")]
        public Category? MainCategory { get; set; }
    }

Edit:
About the second question:
You cannot do that.
The exception ''ProductOrders.MainCategoryId' and 'ProductOrders.SecondCategoryId' are both mapped to column 'CategoryId' in 'ProductOrders', but the properties are contained within the same hierarchy. All properties on an entity type must be mapped to unique different columns.' will be thrown while attempting to create an instance.
So, you can achieve this using EF Core's foreign key configuration.
For example:
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId {  get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class ProductOrders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? MainCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MainCategoryId")]
    public Category? MainCategory { get; set; }

    public int? SecondCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SecondCategoryId")]
    public Category? SecondCategory { get; set; }
}

In DbContext:
The HasForeignKey(p => p.SecondCategoryId) method specifies that SecondCategoryId will serve as a foreign key referencing the Category entity. SecondCategoryId is the foreign key column in the ProductOrders table that points to the Category table.
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // configure the foreign key 'MainCategoryId'
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductOrders>()
            .HasOne(p => p.MainCategory)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.MainCategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        // configure the foreign key 'SecondCategoryId'
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductOrders>()
            .HasOne(p => p.SecondCategory)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.SecondCategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductOrders> ProductOrders { get; set; }
}

